# Clarity on Boolean Algebra and Rings

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to wrap my head around Abstract Algebra, Boolean rings, and it's a little difficult.

So I understand the ring (I believe it's a ring) <ℤ ,x, +, -, 0, 1 > is normal integer arithmetic stuff. We can add and multiply in it and still be in ℤ (All integers), but you can't divide because you may end up outside of ℤ.

So then my question is:

with the algebra (I don't believe it's a ring) <{0,1}<sup>w</sup>, |, &, ~, 0<sup>w</sup>, 1<sup>w</sup>> where {0,1}<sup>w</sup> denotes all strings of 1's and 0's of w length, and a<sup>w</sup> denotes a string consisting of w repetitions of symbol a. are the | and & functions considered multiplication and addition? And if so why do they behave differently in the boolean algebra? because 1010<sub>2</sub> | 0111<sub>2</sub> = 1111<sub>2</sub> which is like 
10<sub>10</sub> | 7<sub>10</sub> = 15<sub>10</sub>. but 10<sub>10</sub> **x** 
7<sub>10</sub> does not equal 15<sub>10</sub>. so why would | be considered multiplication? (again if it actually **is** considered multiplication).

EDIT: You know a couple years back I hated math, now look where I am lmao.

Comment: I do not get why we have $1010|0111=1111$.

Comment: because the truth table for each digit turns out to be 1.